# Lightning aura component response.getReturnValue JSON.Parse

Tags: json, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am geeting Account Id from apex class into aura component. I am getting the Account Id from the apex class but when I try to save it in a attribute it is not saving. Instead I put JSON.stringify to get the JSON value as string. It works but the id is saving like "0015600000dzdF****" with the inverted comas. When I put JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue))) it is not saving in the attribute.

```
let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
                component.set("v.AccountId",result);
                console.log('From Controller: ' + component.get("v.AccountId"));
```

and the attribute.

```
<aura:attribute name="AccountId" type="String" default="" />
```

What am I doing wrong?